# Is it worth to optimize my post system in this way?

Tags: php, sql, optimization

Let's say I have two tables, **post** and **user**. Now let's create two approaches:

1. Use a join on **post.userID** and **user.ID**
2. Select a post; when it is being processed, look up its **userID**; if the user has already been selected (in the script, not cached, but cached "in memory") use these data in orded to achieve a complete post. If the user has not been selected; execute a query to select the user from the user from the database. Retrieve and store the data for further use (always in memory).

Both methods will work, though the first one will make one "big" request, while the second one will make many "small" requests. To my eyes the second one would be better in a huge environment and inconvenient in a small one (vice versa for the second one).

Now let's define three scenarios:

1. Few posts by few users
2. Many posts by few users
3. Many posts by many users

I would like to understand exactly when the two methods will be or not convenient.
Here are my thoughts so far.

1. In the first case both methods would be *almost* the same
2. In the second case the second method *SHOULD* be better since selecting few user will result in few queries.
3. In the third case I think the second method would fit better though I can't really make up my mind.

Is what I said correct? Is there a particular reason I shouldn't adopt second method? Are there any pros/cons to add to what I said ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, doing one "big request" as you name it with a carefully designed join with indexes will be much faster in any case than doing an n*n queries against the database.

If the data portions are small (user tables usually do not hold much data), the overhead for always running one query with a one row result gives a bad performance. Even if you cache data afterwards in memory, in the worst case you have 1000 posts of 1000 different users.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience :)